# Why do I get these weird errors when using pow() for my game?

Tags: mathematics, c

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfm5eKc.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get this error when trying to use `pow()`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/NanoComp/libctl/issues/1), you need to add `-lm` to the flags.

This was supposedly fixed in a newer version.